# RSS feed mis-spelling

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

I have an IFTTT recipe that uses this feed:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=liquibase&sort=newest

The XML has the name as "Newset" rather than "Newest"

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:re="http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0">
    <title type="text">Newset questions tagged liquibase - Stack Overflow</title>
<snip>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.1.13.1848` on meta and `2014.1.13.1298` on sites.